# "show only visible features" doesn't seem to work

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, printing

I'm trying (unsuccesfully) to place the attribute table next to a map containing the same in print composer. Let's say for example my map in the primary window contains 6 districts and my map in the print composer only shows 1 district. If I unselect the "show only visible features" box then my table shows all entries (e.g. from 6 districts). However when I select the "show only visible features" it shows **only** the title row of the attribute table: **it does not show any of the data entries**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Under `Settings -> Options`, General Tab you can select the behaviour of the attribute table. You might scroll down to see it.

These settings overrides the selection in the attribute table itself.

Answer (score 1):

there is a control for how many rows are shown, often it defaults to 0. Also if your projections are different, if the layer the attributes are coming from is different to the crs of the map, then this feature may not work.